# Avoid line wrap on sup element

Tags: css

I'm trying to avoid a line wrap on a sup however the element before is a link element and I don't want the sup to be linked.  Whats the best way to force no linebreak on the last word and the sup?

```
<a href="#">My Name:</a> <sup>*</sup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` !

```
<a href="#">My Name:</a>&nbsp;<sup>*</sup>
```

If for some reason, you don't want a space between your elements, you should wrap them both with a container using `white-space` property with `nowrap` as following :

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><a href="#">My Name:</a> <sup>*</sup></span>
```

(NB: inline style is used for the example only)

Comment: Nice simple solution using the `&nbsp;` character. +1

Comment: change "class" to "style" in above example.

Comment: Right @Val ! Updated.